# Replace a single value in a column of a dataframe with 3 new column values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I would effectively like to replace a single value in a column (based on a criteria) with 3 new column values. For example:

| Ch | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 min |
| A | 1 min |
| B | 2 min |
| B | 2 min |

| A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

| B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

In the above table, If Ch==A, then I would like to see (All values from table 2 repeated twice and so on so forth for Ch==B etc):

| ColA | ColB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **2** | **3** |
| **1** | **3** | **4** |
| **1** | **1** | **2** |
| *1* | *2* | *3* |
| *1* | *3* | *4* |
| *1* | *1* | *2* |

How can I go about doing this efficiently? Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried replacing the value C, however I am not sure of how to insert 3 new columns.

Comment: The input is unclear, do you have 3 DataFrames? Can you provide the constructor(s)?

Comment: Hi @mozway - Yes, that is correct, I have 3 different dataframes at the moment, but would like 1 big dataframe as the result, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can `concat` and `merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Ch': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Time': ['1 min', '1 min', '2 min', '2 min']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1, 2, 1], 'A2': [2, 3, 1], 'A3': [3, 4, 2]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'B1': [1, 1], 'B2': [2, 1], 'B3': [1, 1]})


d = {'A': df2, 'B': df3}

df1.merge(pd.concat({k: v.set_axis(['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC'], axis=1)
                     for k,v in d.items()}
                   ).droplevel(1),
          left_on='Ch', right_index=True
          )
```

Output:

```
  Ch   Time  ColA  ColB  ColC
0  A  1 min     1     2     3
0  A  1 min     2     3     4
0  A  1 min     1     1     2
1  A  1 min     1     2     3
1  A  1 min     2     3     4
1  A  1 min     1     1     2
2  B  2 min     1     2     1
2  B  2 min     1     1     1
3  B  2 min     1     2     1
3  B  2 min     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway - this is brilliant, I am going to try this, but just out of curiosity, is there a way to do this programatically (as I anticipate the number of input dataframes to go up ) and shall keep you posted.

Comment: @user21214736 as long as you have a dictionary of key/dataframe, the above solution will work. If you want to rely on variable names, this is bad practice and you should use a dictionary.